# SwiftUI Text bound to state uses different animation

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to implement a slide transition between two SwiftUI views, this is working well except for when I come to draw a Text label using bound state data. In this event the Text control decides to use a completely different animation to the rest of the View. The Text that is bound uses a fade in animation, as opposed to a slide animation.

How can I ensure that the Label that is bound to state draws with the same animation as the rest of the view?

```
struct ParentView: View {

  @State var step = 1
  @State var userSelection: String? = nil

  var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
      VStack {
        Spacer()
        
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
          FirstView(userSelection: $userSelection, step: $step)
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
            .background(Color.red)
          
          SecondView(userSelection: $userSelection, step: $step)
            .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
            .background(Color.blue)
        }
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width * 2)
        .offset(x: -geometry.size.width * CGFloat(step - 1))
        .animation(.default, value: UUID()) // Animation applied here!!
      }
    }
  }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    @Binding var userSelection: String?
    @Binding var step: Int
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
          Text("Option 1")
            .onTapGesture {
              userSelection = "Option 1"
              step += 1
            }

            Text("Option 2")
            .onTapGesture {
              userSelection = "Option 2"
              step += 1
            }
        }
    }
}


struct SecondView: View {
  @Binding var userSelection: String?
  @Binding var step: Int
  
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Go Back")
            .onTapGesture {
              userSelection = nil
              step -= 1
            }

            Text(userSelection ?? "")
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's because `userSelection` is undergoing its own change as the view is switching.

You can fix it by adding `.drawingGroup()` to `SecondView`:

```swift
      SecondView(userSelection: $userSelection, step: $step)
        .frame(width: geometry.size.width, height: geometry.size.height)
        .background(Color.blue)
        .drawingGroup() // <-- HERE
```

BTW, using a `ZStack` might be a simpler way to achieve the animation. Here's how:

```swift
struct ParentView: View {

    @State var userSelection: String? = nil

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if userSelection == nil {
                FirstView(userSelection: $userSelection)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.red)
                    .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
            } else {
                SecondView(userSelection: $userSelection)
                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
                    .background(Color.blue)
                    .drawingGroup()
                    .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
            }
        }
    }
}

struct FirstView: View {
    @Binding var userSelection: String?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Option 1")
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation { userSelection = "Option 1" }
                }
            Text("Option 2")
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation { userSelection = "Option 2" }
                }
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    @Binding var userSelection: String?

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Go Back")
                .onTapGesture {
                    withAnimation { userSelection = nil }
                }
            Text(userSelection ?? "")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Neat, thanking you very much for the information provided, you've resolved my issue. 